# Servers unexpectedly change to BDC on AD?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I've got two AD virtual machines runnning on HyperV. AD1(PDC) syncs its time with pool.ntp.org and AD2(BDC) syncs with AD1 to get the time correct. Both are windows server 2008 servers.

This worked fine for a while, but lately servers seem to drop out from AD1 and authenticate with AD2 instead, even though AD1 is up and running.

I've tried to shut down AD2 and restart all servers on the domain to force them to authenticate to AD1 which works fine. But whenever I put AD2 on the network again servers will still auth to AD2 on reboot.

This behavior is unknown to me and I'm having a hard time troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: What exactly are you considering as a problem?

Comment: *I'm having a hard time troubleshooting the issue.* - I'm not surprised. There's no 'issue' to troubleshoot. This is expected behaviour. You might as well troubleshoot why water is wet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. This doesn't have anything to do with time synchronization. Your time sync configuration appears to be correct from what you've stated in your question. The DC that holds the PDCe role should sync with a reliable external time source. All other domain members should sync with the domain hierarchy. This includes all other Domain Controllers.
2. Stop calling them PDC and BDC. That terminology is no longer valid and is a hint that you're not exactly up to snuff in your understanding of AD. AD uses a Multiple-Master model (referred to as Flexible Single Master Operations or FSMO), which you can read about at this link. - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/197132
3. Your domain clients are behaving exactly as expected. An AD domain client can authenticate to any available Domain Controller. You should neither try to control that behavior nor discourage it. The fact that you see this as a problem that needs to be solved is another clue that you really don't have a good understanding of AD. It might serve you to do some in depth reading on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

if AD2 is suitable as a good time source, i don't think there's a need to change the topology.

if AD2 has itself incorrect time and is therefore not a good choice, i would recommend to ensure that AD2 has the correct time (which in replication solves incorrect times on clients).

we saw something related at one of our customers (where one DC had in fact incorrect time).
it seems that the timeservice on ad2 is still announcing as authorative.

you may set the timeserver on ad2 so that it's no longer considered as reliable timeserver.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/w32time/archive/2008/05/29/to-be-reliable-or-not-to-be-reliable.aspx

otherwise you may use GPOs to assign the timeserver explicitly - as i personally would still prefer the first choice